# Angular (16) Material Responsive Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've been wanting to make the angular material table in my angular 16 app more responsive and work on mobile screens too, am I missing something or is the table only made to work on full sized screens?

Today I just have it like the examples here:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

I was wanting it something like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-responsive-strict-mode?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmat-table-responsive%2Fmat-table-responsive.directive.scss

Any tips appreciated

I tried implementing like the one in Angular 12 I linked but no success

Comment: Please read [ask], where it mentions, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so — **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS."

Comment: The Angular 12 example looks really great! Why is that not working for your Angular 16 project? Maybe you can show code of your implementation, and include any errors you may be getting in the console.

Comment: As you would expect, the Material table generally works fine on mobile screens.